# Where are num1 and num2 being defined?

Tags: javascript

I am extremely new please bear with me. This exercise is from Khanacademy. I got the correct answer and it's moving me along in the lesson but I'm still a bit perplexed.

Where is the variable num1 and num2 getting their value?
Is it even being defined?

```
var add = function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
};
var subtract = function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
};
var multiply = function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
};
var divide = function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
};

fill(255, 0, 0);
text("2 + 2 is " + add(2, 2), 10, 20);
text("2 - 2 is " + subtract(2, 2), 10, 50);
text("2 * 2 is " + multiply(2, 2), 10, 80);
text("2 / 2 is " + divide(2, 2), 10, 110);
```

Comment: Take a look at [Javascript functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). `num1` and `num2` are defined in the function definition and the values are passed from the parameters to the function call.

Comment: Dude, make an answer so you can get votes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num1` and `num2` are formal parameters to each of the `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide` functions.

Thus, when you use a construct like `add(2, 2)`, what you are saying is "I want you to go to the `add` variable, take out the function that is living inside it, and run that function where `num1 = 2` and `num2 = 2`."

Several decent guides are available on JavaScript functions, for instance [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) or [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me out! I see it now. All these "shortcuts" are actually making things more difficult...

Answer (score 1):

`num1` and `num2` are parameters of a function.

In that code are defined 4 functions:

- add
- subtract
- multiply
- divide

So, in the final lines what the code is doing is invoking each of those functions, for example:

`add(2, 2)` //This is calling the function `add` with `num1 = 2` and `num2 = 2`

Answer (score 0):

They are being defined as parameters in your functions.

Where do they get initialized? Javascript interpreter initializes them for you when you call those functions.